# empty string condition not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery

`retrievedID` is a string returned by window `localStorage` property in my code as:

```
$(function () {
            var retrievedID = localStorage.getItem('navitemID');
            if ($(retrievedID).val() !== '') {
                $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
                var myID = "#" + retrievedID;
                $(myID).addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

if statement in this code isn't working as expected because despite having an empty string inside `recievedID` variable, code is still entering inside the condition and executing.

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$(retrievedID).val()`? Anything other than an empty string will satisfy the condition.

Comment: So what is console.log($(retrievedID).val()); is pointing out?

Comment: @Thallius: `$(retrievedID).val()` in console is coming as 
undefined

Comment: @phuzi: `$(retrievedID).val()` inside console is coming as undefined while it is empty

Comment: @Oxin, check on if ($(retrievedID).val() != undefined && $(retrievedID).val() !== '')

Comment: `undefined !== ''` will evaluate to true

Comment: @phuzi , then show your solution?

Comment: @Oxin Mandeep has already provided you a solution.

Comment: @Grumpy: your given condition is working but it is also bypassing a string which is not null or empty. That is, it is coming true for `ALL` values.

Comment: @phuzi: `if` condition in Mandeep's solution is always coming as true for all values and hence code inside the if condition is never getting to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check undefined type, add to if condition

```
$(function () {
            var retrievedID = localStorage.getItem('navitemID');
            if ($(retrievedID).val() !== '' ||  typeof $(retrievedID).val() !== "undefined" ) {
                $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
                var myID = "#" + retrievedID;
                $(myID).addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe you should change || to &&

Comment: You should leave out the quotes around undefined, for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: @joronimo `typeof` returns a string which is why the test is against `"undefined"` and not `undefined`